# Hibernate/JPA/HSQLDB Enum issues

Tags: hibernate, jpa, enums, hsqldb

I am using Hibernate annotations and entity manager (JPA) with HSQLDB. So I have an entity with an enum field:

```
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
@Column(name = "access_level")
public AccessLevel getAccessLevel() {
    return accessLevel;
}
```

Where AccessLevel is an enum.  I can persist this, detach, and then query and everything is as it should be.  However, once I close the EntityManagerFactory and everything flushes out to disk and then start again, this field always comes up null.

When I query the database with the HSQLDB Manager, everything is there and the column in this table contains the name of the enum element as it should.  However, when I query, the entity has everything except this field is always null.

I am trying to avoid the user type business and keep it simple.  What confuses me is that it is only after closing the EntityManagerFactory that this happens.  I can persist and detach the object and then merge, query, find or whatever using other EntityManagers and transactions and the enum is handled correctly.

Any clue would be helpful.

Comment: That's very weird. Could you show the generated SQL for the select?

Comment: This appears to be due to my class hierarchy.  I have an entity Person that has a subclass User which has subclasses Player and Employee.  This AccessLevel field is on the Employee entity.  The inheritance strategy is table per class throughout and the root entity that I'm retrieving has a one-to-many to User and Employees in the collection have the null enum only after closing the EntityManagerFactory as I described above.  If I find a specific Employee, the enum is decoded correctly.

Comment: Could you provide some code illustrating 2nd and 3rd paragraphs?

Comment: The issue I was having has to do with using the TABLE_PER_CLASS inheritance strategy.  I've switched to the JOINED strategy and things are behaving correctly.